# sort a dictionary by inner key python

Tags: python

I have a 3 dimensional dictionary

```
 d = ({k1:{k2:{k3:v}}}
       and many more such keys....)
```

Now, I want to sort this dictionary by k3?
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You do know a dict is not ordered, right? Did you want to sort the keys() for a specific usage instead?

Comment: Please be more specific about the result you head for, and provide a working example of such a dictionary (or rather a nested tuple?). Please tell _why_ one would need to accomplish such obscure task. Probably you should rather reconsider your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 sorted_keys = sorted(d.keys(),key=lambda x:d[x]['key2']['key3'])
```

will sort the keys for you ... (since dictionaries are by definition unsorted)

Comment: this will return the sorted keys, not the dictionary sorted.

Comment: @moooeeeep: There is no such thing as a storted dictionary in python. There *is* an OrderedDict subclass, but that's something different.

Comment: as mentioned in the answer and comments dictionaries are unsorted ... hence all you can sort are the keys..

Comment: _and_ the keys and values in the nested dictionaries.